# Why free abelian chain complexes in homology?

Tags: homology-cohomology

I was wondering is there any specific reason why the chain complexes in homology are free abelian?

Thanks in advance

Comment: As opposed to what? I don't understand your question.

Comment: In what homology? You can certainly take the homology of any chain complex, whether or not the groups are free.

Comment: my bad i got confused. I thought the groups should be free abelian no matter what.

Answer (score 2):

This question also occurred to me when first studying homology. To be a bit more precise, in singular homology, one can ask why the default construction of an $n$-chain, an element of $C_n(X)$, is defined to be the free abelian group with basis the $n$-simplices $\sigma_{\alpha}:\Delta^n\to X$ (the continuous mappings of the standard $n$-simplex into $X$).

One reason is that $n$-chains are then finite formal linear sums $\sum a_{\alpha}\sigma_{\alpha}$ with coefficients $a_{\alpha}\in\mathbb{Z}$, which can be used to build "$n$-surfaces in $X$." In particular, we can build an $n$-chain which is a sum of "$n$-spheres in $X$" where each sphere can "wrap around itself" any number of times in any direction (to be more precise, each term $a\sigma$ consists of $a$ copies of $\sigma$, with the orientation reversed for negative $a$). For homology using non-integer coefficients, we have to discard the "number of wrappings" idea.

We then build a chain complex, a sequence of homomorphisms of $n$-chains $\partial_{n}\colon C_{n}\left(X\right)\to C_{n-1}\left(X\right)$ with $\partial_{n}\partial_{n+1}=0$, which can be viewed in terms of these copies of spheres:

[image]

Finally, the $n$th homology group is defined as $H_{n}(X)\equiv\textrm{Ker}\partial_{n}/\textrm{Im}\partial_{n+1}$, i.e. the group of cosets consisting of homologous $n$-cycles that can all be obtained from each other by adding the boundary of some $(n+1)$-volume in $X$.

For simple spaces, we then expect that $H_n$ will be a direct product of $\mathbb{Z}$ components, one for each “$n$-dimensional hole” in $X$ that is not the boundary of a $(n+1)$-volume, since each such hole can be "wrapped around" any number of times in either direction, and none of these "wrappings" are homologous.

This viewpoint is worked out in more detail [here](https://www.mathphysicsbook.com/mathematics/algebraic-topology/counting-holes-that-arent-boundaries/).